# How to insert windows phone page to pivot item?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, user-controls

I have a problem with `Pivot` control. How can I insert xaml page with content to `Pivot` item? Is it even possible?

When I’m storing everything in one file it’s really hard to take control over my own application layout.

I want something like this:

- on main page should be pivot control with items.
- content of those items should be in separated xaml files (there is no dependency between pages)

Comment: Did you try creating UserControl for each PivotItem ?

Comment: Yes. But how to connect them to the pivotItem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add correct namespace to Page:

```
xmlns:view="clr-namespace:YourApp.Controls"
```

and in Pivot:

```
<Pivot>
   <PivotItem Name="first">
     <view:FirstUserControl DataContext="{Binding YourViewModel}"/>
   </PivotItem>
</Pivot>
```

And in view namespace you need to create a [User Control](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32825/How-to-Creating-a-WPF-User-Control-using-it-in-a-W). The link is about WPF but in WP7 there is the same system.

Also, you can create [Custom Control](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Creating-a-WP7-Custom-Control-in-7-Steps) from PivotItem.