# Reaching MainPage.Xaml.cs click handler functions from App.Xaml.cs in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am asking for this because when i do a switchable application bars in pivot page (four page) i have to hard code the handlers in app.xaml.cs? or is there a way to call the handlers from App.xaml.cs inside ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, for example you can make your eventhandler `public` and `static`:

```
public static void StaticButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Event from App.xaml.cs!");
}
// ten at any Page you can subscribe like this:
myButton.Click += App.StaticButton_Click;
```

You can also get to your eventhandler by App instance like this (just make your handler public):

```
public void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Event from App.xaml.cs!");
}
// then you can subscribe like this:
myButton.Click += (App.Current as App).Button_Click;
```

But you must be aware that those methods have limitations - you can't easily get to your Page's elements in this handler - it's universal so you would have to pass some information to it from which Page it was invoked and so on (for example you can use some other handlers). But maybe as it is designed as universal so maybe there will be no need for such a thing - everything depends on your App.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23143201/different-usercontrol-xaml-pages-on-a-pivot can you look at it?

Comment: how can i append xaml for each pivot item?

Comment: @user3529738 Questioning under an answer isn't a good method to find a solution for other problems. It would be much better if you had improved your question - add some code, tell what you have tried and were you have encountered problems. Try to read your question - it is unclear, so how somebody can answer it? Btw you can have a look [at this question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12785810/2681948)

Comment: pivot is in the mainpage.xaml, but when i want to put 4 application bars for 4 cases of pivot items, it searches click handlers from app.xaml.cs itself. but click handlers are in mainpage.xaml.cs, btw i have used MSDN tutorial for addind extra bars, b ut i cant control click handlers on the application bar http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394036(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: @user3529738 Try to define your AppBar (the code from MSDN) not in Application.Resources but in your Mainpage.xaml in PhoneApplicationPage.Resources.

Comment: ApplicationBar = ((ApplicationBar)Application.Current.Resources["AppBar1"]);
 how can i edit this in cs? i put the xaml on PhoneapplicationPage.Resources

Comment: @user3529738 THen you just use this.Resources["AppBar1"]. Try to find some tutorials, articles, there are many in the internet.

Comment: thanks i have tried,                     ApplicationBar = ((ApplicationBar)PhoneApplicationPage.Resources["one"]);
not working

Comment: ApplicationBar = this.Resources["one"] as ApplicationBar;